# Why can I not find com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, spotbugs

Since yesterday I get the problem that the spotbugs gradle plugin cannot be found.
The Version we are looking for is 4.7.1.

Gradle Error:
Could not find com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin

I configured the following repositories:

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/4.7.1/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-4.7.1.pom
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/4.7.1/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-4.7.1.pom
- https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/4.7.1/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-4.7.1.pom

The configuration is like described in the documentation and as a said it worked for months without problems.

Any ideas what is wrong now? New Repository, major structural change,...?

Comment: Check this out:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/4.7.1

Comment: Or this:
https://nexus.pentaho.org/repository/proxy-public-3rd-party-release/gradle/plugin/com/github/spotbugs/snom/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/4.7.1/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-4.7.1.pom

Comment: The first link says it available here: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2, but this link is not working.

Comment: I don't know what is happening but You can switch the repository as long as the package is correct.

Comment: I can suggest to use as mention here: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.spotbugs

Comment: Other Issue I can suspect is may be https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/ was using/redirecting to jcenter, and since jcenter is deprecated and no longer working, so is https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/, more info: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/